# is string invalid json object?

Tags: json, string

I have a question, and I can't find any doc about it.
Is string invalid object for json?

For an example, you can do this in any browser:
JS:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("asdf")));
```

Java (jackson):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String string = mapper.writeValueAsString("asdf");
TextNode node = (TextNode)mapper.readTree(string);
System.out.println(node.getTextValue());
```

PHP:

```
echo json_decode(json_encode("asdf"));
```

But, as I can see, this parsers did not work with string as root object:

1. [http://json.parser.online.fr](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization)
2. [http://jsonparseronline.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization)

Also, from [SWIFT documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization) -

> The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary.

According to this question, is it invalid to return json-formatted string from your controller (endpoint)?

```
example.com/notes/2/title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://jsonlint.com, "asdf" is valid JSON. Some parsers are stricter than others. You definitely can't use it as the root for any other data though, because it's just a string, not an object or array.

Having said that, if you want an absolute definition, try reading the relevant RFC rather than documentation of a particular programming language. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259 dated Decemeber 2017 is the latest (at the time of writing this answer), as far as I know.

Specifically https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-2 says

> A JSON text is a sequence of tokens.  The set of tokens includes six
> structural characters, strings, numbers, and three literal names.
>
> A JSON text is a serialized value.  Note that certain previous
> specifications of JSON constrained a JSON text to be an object or an
> array.

And later

> Here are three small JSON texts containing only values:
>
> ```
>    "Hello world!"
>
>    42
>
>    true
> ```

So I would assume that the different parsers mentioned are implementing different versions of the spec.